# Django - best practice for getting ID from querystring into edit view

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm wondering what the acceptable best practice is for pulling an id from a url for use in the edit view. Most example code I see uses slugs, which I don't need to deal with because SEO is not a concern.

Say I have something like:

```
def article_edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        #a = get_object_or_404(Article, **?XXX?**)
        #a = Article.objects.get(pk=**?XXX?**)

        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=a) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            form.save()
            return redirect('/articles/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ArticleForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'article_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Where I have commented out two possible options for populating a with an Article object based on the ID submitted in the POST. The **?XXX?** indicates that I'm not sure how to reference the passed in id.

Any input on those two options, as well as alternative options are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passed in `id` should go in the url itself, like:

```
url(r'^articles/(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$', 'views.article_edit', name = 'article_edit'),
```

Then, in the view you can reference it from the view argument `id`:

```
def article_edit(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=id)
```

Also, take a look at [Writing a simple form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form) chapter of django "polls" tutorial - the same approach is used.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there any reason why you build the url with id before the action? I had mine already structured as articles/edit/id.

Comment: Yes, you can do it either way, no problem with it.

Comment: Thanks! Also, for the benefit of future readers, I had an error with the above that resulted in "Value error: need more than 1 value to unpack". I had to change to "def article_edit(request, pk=id)"; for some reason that second parameter wasn't automatically being recognized as the id.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
urls.py :
url(r'^articles/(?P<article_id>\d+)/edit/$', 'views.article_edit', name = 'article'),

views.py:
def article_edit(request, id):
if request.method == 'POST': 
    article = get_object_or_404(Article,id=article_id)
```